# UIButton in SMS App

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibutton

How can I recreate the UIButtons displayed at the top of the SMS app (such as the "Load Earlier Messages" button). They look like pretty standard UIButtons except with a gradient, a slight shadow drop shadow and inner shadow, and a bluer border. Does Apple use a stretchable UIImage to make these or are they created programmatically (and how)?

[image]

Comment: Just create image assets that look like that and use them for the button's background image.

Comment: That was my fallback plan. I like to create things programmatically whenever possible though so I don't have to worry about screen size.

Comment: Usually you design button with a fixed height, so you'd only need a few assets, and the designed images always tend to look a bit more polished for stuff like that. If you wanted to create it programmatically, you could draw the shapes and use a `CGGradient` to fill it.

Answer (score 1):

My favorite solution to this problem is to create a segmented control with exactly one segment.  You end up with a nice-looking button. Here's how I do it programmatically:

```
UISegmentedControl* takePhotoButton = 
     [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"Take Photo"]];
takePhotoButton.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
takePhotoButton.frame = CGRectMake(55,336,110,38);
takePhotoButton.tintColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16]
                                                       forKey:UITextAttributeFont];
[takePhotoButton setTitleTextAttributes:attributes
                               forState:UIControlStateNormal];
takePhotoButton.momentary = YES;
[takePhotoButton addTarget:self
                    action:@selector(onTakePhoto:)
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[self.view addSubview:takePhotoButton];
```

Comment: Although that does make a nice looking button, I'm looking for an exact replication of the buttons shown above. Thank you for the tip though!